# Present view controller programmatically from NSWindowController

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nswindowcontroller

I am working with swift 4 for macOS and I can show another view controller programmatically with this code:

```
@IBAction func showVC(_ sender: NSButton) {
    let vc = NSStoryboard(name: NSStoryboard.Name(rawValue: "Main"), bundle: nil).instantiateController(withIdentifier: NSStoryboard.SceneIdentifier(rawValue: "MyVC")) as! NSViewController
    self.presentViewController(vc, asPopoverRelativeTo: sender.bounds, of: sender, preferredEdge: .maxX, behavior: .transient)
}
```

Now I would like to do the same from a NSWindowController, but I get below "error":

`value of type 'WindowController' has no member 'presentViewController'`

Is there another way to realize it?

**NEXT TRY**

```
   @IBAction func showVC(_ sender: NSToolbarItem) {
    let vc = NSStoryboard(name: NSStoryboard.Name(rawValue: "Main"), bundle: nil).instantiateController(withIdentifier: NSStoryboard.SceneIdentifier(rawValue: "MyVC")) as! NSViewController
self.contentViewController?.presentViewController(x, asPopoverRelativeTo: sender.view!.bounds, of: sender.view!, preferredEdge: .maxX, behavior: .transient)

    }
```

the app crashes on the second line with:

`fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

i check following:

```
print(sender.view?.bounds ?? "No bounds")
print(sender.view ?? "No view")
```

**Print result**

```
No bounds
No view
```

But why??

Comment: Is WindowController child of the NSViewController? NSViewController has a `presentViewController(_:asPopoverRelativeTo:of:preferredEdge:behavior:)`method.

Comment: You should not use ViewControllers with NSWindowController. Just add Windows to your NSWindowController

Comment: explanation. my window controller has a toolbar with items. one of this item has an IBAction in the Window Controller class, which should show a popover. and for this situation a searching a solution

Comment: The line starting with let vc = NSStoryboard doesn't make sense.  I'll give you a hint: contentViewController.

Comment: thx for the hint. I updated my first post with my next try and problem :/

Answer (score 4):

try this :

```
let storyBoard = NSStoryboard(name: NSStoryboard.Name(rawValue: "Main"), bundle: nil)
let mainViewController : NSViewController = storyBoard.instantiateController(withIdentifier: NSStoryboard.SceneIdentifier(rawValue: "myVC")) as! NSViewController
self.contentViewController!.presentViewController(mainViewController, asPopoverRelativeTo: sender.bounds, of: sender, preferredEdge: .maxY, behavior: .transient)
```